# wordpress custom pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have make a simple wpquery for get all events. Then with an "if" condition I check if the event start today and if yes, show the title post.
My problem is with pagination, because i don't know make a pagination based on the loop result.

```
 if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
 elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
 else { $paged = 1; }

 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'posts_per_page' => '5',
'order' => 'ASC',
'paged' => $paged   
 );

 query_posts($args); 

if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $event_start = get('event_start');

    // if the event start is today show the title post
    if($event_start == date('d.m.Y')){
       the_title();
    }
endwhile;
// PROBLEM: show the pagination for all events
wp_pagenavi();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and use the [custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to only pull the relevant results. This way pagination will work directly and you won't be retrieving and looping over posts that are not required.

As a side note, you may also find [this answer useful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) as to why you shouldn't use query_posts.

Comment: thk for the answer. My problem is that i have custom field "event start" in this format: gg.mm.YYYY With this format i can't use custom field parameters.

Comment: In your example you're comparing gg.mm.YYYY with m/d/Y ? I'm not sure how that will ever match.

Comment: d.m.Y != gg.mm.YYYY

Nevertheless, I don't understand why you can't use the custom field parameters of WP_Query with your custom field? Have you at least tried it?

Comment: I repeat "Nevertheless, I don't understand why you can't use the custom field parameters of WP_Query with your custom field? Have you at least tried it?"